# Надо ли использовать Fragments?

Tags: android

Встал вопрос необходимости переписывания приложения под Fragments API. Проложение содержит только `Avtivity`, причем каждая отвечает только за один скрин и не будет содержать нескольких, как в примере SDK. Надо ли переписывать, чтобы каждая активность содержала только один фрагмент или теперь должна быть одна активность, а все скрины надо переписать на фрагменты, которые будет менеджерить эта одна активность? В общем, не понятно, стоит ли вообще что-то трогать и если стоит, как теперь должно быть организовано приложение.

Answer (score 1):

Ну если НАДО - переписывай, вообще фрагменты рекомендуется использовать для планшетных экранов, т.е. больше 10" и они сделаны как удобный способ  управления свободным пространством экрана, т.е. в некоторых местах, где это кажется правильным надо юзать их, где-то лучше создать новое активити и перейти на него...

Comment: Какая структура тогда должна быть у приложения? Для каждой активности свой фрагмент? или одна активность, а все остальные переделать на фрагменты?

Comment: Зависит от юзабилити приложения, в фрагменты можно вынести меню для навигации, некоторые элементы относящиеся к активити.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы в будущем планируете адаптировать свое приложение также под планшеты (одно и тоже приложение будет иметь разные лайуты экраов под смартфоны и планшеты) то тогда ответ однозначен, да, НАДО переходить на фрагменты. Если же ответ отрицательный то тогда не стоит затевать переписывание рабочего приложения.